# Not able to generate controller and views from Entity Framework Core model in CLI

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core

In ASP.NET Core 3.1 I am looking for a way to generate controllers and CRUD views from the command line in Windows from my models using the Entity Framework scaffolding engine. It seems everyone is using Visual Studio to do it in the tutorials like it's the only way. No one is using VS Code. Is it impossible on Windows 10?

I use this command.

```
dotnet aspnet-codegenerator controller -name RecipeIngredientsController -m RecipeIngredient -dc CookingContext --relativeFolderPath Controllers --useDefaultLayout --referenceScriptLibraries
```

Every time I attempt this I am returned with the same error.

> Finding the generator 'controller'... No code generators found with
> the name 'controller'    at
> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.CodeGeneratorsLocator.GetCodeGenerator(String
> codeGeneratorName)    at
> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.CodeGenCommand.Execute(String[]
> args)

I have looked at so much documentation so yes I have seen all this. It didn't help me solve the error. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/tools/dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Also someone on a Github issue suggested copying these 2 folders to the Templates folder on Ubuntu which I tried as well on my Windows 10 computer.

- ControllerGenerator
- ViewGenerator

And yet I still get the same error. Here are the models I am using.

**Ingredient.cs**

```cs
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

    namespace DTEditorLeftJoinSample.Models
    {
        public class Ingredient
        {
            public int ID {get;set;}
            [Display(Name = "Ingredient Name")]
            public string IngredientName {get;set;}

            public ICollection<RecipeIngredient> RecipeIngredient { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

**Recipe.cs**

```cs
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
    
    namespace DTEditorLeftJoinSample.Models
    {
        public class Recipe
        {
            public int ID { get; set; } 
            
            public string Title {get;set;}
            public string Descriptions {get;set;}
            public string Directions {get;set;} 
    
            public ICollection<RecipeIngredient> RecipeIngredient {get;set;}    
        }
    }
```

**RecipeIngredient.cs**

```cs
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace DTEditorLeftJoinSample.Models
{
    public class RecipeIngredient
    {
        public int ID {get;set;}

        [Display(Name = "Recipe ID")]
        public int RecipeID { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Ingredient ID")]
        public int IngredientID { get; set; }
    
        public int quantity {get;set;}        
        public Recipe Recipe {get;set;}
        public Ingredient Ingredient {get;set;}
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please share your asp.net core version? It seems there is some [issue](https://github.com/dotnet/Scaffolding/issues/1347) for specific version of dotnet core. I suggest you could try to update to 3.1.4 and try again.

Comment: Hi @BrandoZhang. You referring to the steps TB-Development recommended? It sadly didn't work. Yes I was using 3.1.0 before. Now I use the version you mention and rebuild it all. Same error.

Comment: Hello, just to let you know that I have the exact same problem. I put everything up to date, using most recent version of everything (VS, SDK, Generator, etc) and I have the exact same error. 2023-03-17

Answer (score 0):

Even in Visual Studio right clicking on the controller and adding the "New Scaffolded Item"  didn't work. Kept getting the error "There was an error running the selected code generator package restore failed."

The only fix was to upgrade the framework from .NET Core 3.1 to the latest version .NET 5 and the packages to 5.0.1 which was ridiculously simple as shown [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/31-to-50?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio).

All you're doing is changing the project file to this and upgrading each NuGet package you installed via the package manager GUI in Visual Studio.

If you want to learn to do all this please see [my blog here](https://layersofabstraction.github.io/DTLeftJoins2.html)

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp5.0</TargetFramework>
    <AddRazorSupportForMvc>true</AddRazorSupportForMvc>
  </PropertyGroup>


  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="DataTables-Editor-Server" Version="1.9.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson" Version="5.0.0" />    
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="5.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="5.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="5.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```